# Combining formulas

Tags: regex, tableau-api

Please help me with combining these two formulas:

1. `REGEXP_EXTRACT([resolution],'(\d{2}:\d{2})')`
2. `IF CONTAINS([resolution],"closed")  and NOT CONTAINS([resolution],"resolution") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Example:
I have lines

1.resolution(01:01) Completed repair equipments

2.resolution(01:02) Preventive maintenance

3.The problem is not current

4.resolution(01:03) Completed repair equipments. The problem is not current

I have 2 calculated field.

1. REGEXP_EXTRACT([resolution],'(\d{2}:\d{2})') - find numbers 01:01,01:02,01:03
2. IF CONTAINS([resolution],"closed")  and NOT CONTAINS([resolution],"resolution") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END - excludes records:3.The problem is not current

I want to make a formula which combined two formulas and  displays numbers:01:01,01:02,01:03

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to use these in a calculated field?

You should be able to pull the initial one into your second calculated field. So if you create your first calculated field(analysis->create calculated field) and lets call it "Calc 1". So this will have your initial formula:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([resolution],'(\d{2}:\d{2})')
```

Then create a second calculated field and call it "Calc 2". In this formula just update your original to call the first calculated field which contains your formula:

```
IF CONTAINS([Calc 1],"closed") and NOT CONTAINS([Calc 1],"resolution") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I try it your formula but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set?